# How do I test a component were the output goes to a database using Cucumber?

Tags: java, testing, tdd, cucumber, domain-driven-design

Recently there was a discussion in my team about how to properly test a component of our system where the output is stored in a database. We use DDD to create our system so the component ultimately talks to a repository that has different stores implemented to talk to a MongoDB. As testing framework we use Cucumber and the database we use for testing is an in-memory version of mongo.

Up until now, all our scenarios had a command as input and the output was an event so our assertions were done on the event. But now we have a scenario where the event is processed and the result is stored in a database. The result can be retrieved using a rest call after that happens.

The discussion was about the way to test these two last scenarios. For some, the correct way is to check the in-memory database after the event is processed because that's the output of the system. The ultimate part of the system are the stores and they have to be tested as well as part of the scenario. Testing what the in-memory database contains is the right way as the stores are still using the same production ready logic to write the output. For convenience, we would use the repositories to retrieve this data as is easier this way, even when we need to use something not related to the scenario at hand.

On the other hand, for some people we shouldn't be checking the database as that's another component which we shouldn't be accessing for the test. Instead, because in this case the rest call is just retrieving the data, we should use the rest call as part of the test to verify the output. This way, our scenario would include this 2 parts, the storing and the retrieving instead of splitting the tests.

Is there any correct answer to this? Are we missing any point here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say verifying with a REST call is the correct way to do it here. Otherwise it wouldn't really be blackbox testing, and your test will depend on internal implementation details (your database structure). You usually want to see what effect your application has on the "outside world", and your database is not part of this IMO.

This is all assuming the tests you are creating are intended to be blackbox tests. If it's an integration test (~grey box I guess?) then IMO checking the database using the repository is probably a better idea.

If it's intended to be a unit test, the dependencies of your component should be mocked. You can then use the mocks to verify that your component called the repository correctly.

If I misunderstood something, do let me know. :)

Comment: We want this to be a test to verify that a component of the system (a standalone component in this case) works as expected. As far as I know, integration tests would involve all the components developed for the application in a test environment, with a real database. In this case, it's just one of them, using its endpoints. The system is already unit tested, it's about testing end to end. What would be your opinion on this if there wasn't any REST call to get that data? Maybe this input data could be used for another operation rather than to just be store to be fetched by the user.

Comment: @Kilian As a general point I'd say your test should be checking the data the same way a client using this component would access the data. There should always be a way your scenario is visible to the outside of your component. Sometimes you can ask for the data via a REST call, sometimes your component calls someone else with a REST call but there should always be some effect you can measure without going into the internals. That said, it's not always *easy* to verify the effects from the outside. (the effect could be scheduled for example). Then checking the internals might be better. :)

Comment: That sounds reasonable :D so, just to clarify, in a test like this were the component is tested end to end, only the API provided should be used for testing the result. If, for example, a system requires 3 different messages to come to a result, the test should send the 3 of them together to fetch the data later but not test each in isolation, even when they use complex logic or the result of each could be checked in the DB. I guess to check that processing that's why the unit tests exist. This would just test the behaviour of the system given external input.

Comment: Something that came up talking to one colleague was; what if the REST call is broken? Every test that relies on this call would fail when the problem is related to a different user action. The logic behind the first operation that could be jms message may be working fine but this wouldn't be visible as the operation that verifies it is broken.

Comment: @Kilian In my opinion, that's correct. If it takes three messages to get some observable result, then you should deliver all three before trying to verify anything. It's a good idea to view end-to-end testing as blackbox testing. What happens inside the box is unknown and we don't care about it. If the box looks the same, then nothing has happened. :) The inside of the box is the concern of unit tests and low-level integration tests.

Comment: @Kilian Definitely a valid point. We are kind of trading away error localization for realism when we're doing these full scenario end-to-end tests. In my opinion the end-to-end-test should still fail, since the scenario then is broken. Unit- and low-level integration tests should help with error localization.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!Really appreaciate them.